# Using arduino to control leds as a pattern

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, led

I have this code here which sends some keys to windows and also lights up an led attached under each button. I think its right so the led will toggle with the button. What I wanted to achieve **ontop of this** was so that if no button states hadn't changed for 30 seconds then it goes into a mode where all three leds flash rapidly 3 times then the leds randomly flashes (Like a pinball machine when its not in use). After any input then it goes back to the normal mode

```
    /* Arduino USB Keyboard HID demo
 * Cut/Copy/Paste Keys
 */

#define KEY_LEFT_CTRL   0x01
#define KEY_LEFT_SHIFT  0x02
#define KEY_RIGHT_CTRL  0x10
#define KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT 0x20

uint8_t buf[8] = { 
  0 };  /* Keyboard report buffer */

#define PIN_COPY 5
#define PIN_CUT 6
#define PIN_PASTE 7
#define LED_COPY 8
#define LED_CUT 9
#define LED_PASTE 10

int state = 1;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(PIN_COPY, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_CUT, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_PASTE, INPUT);
  // Enable internal pull-ups
  digitalWrite(PIN_COPY, 1); 
  digitalWrite(PIN_CUT, 1);
  digitalWrite(PIN_PASTE, 1); 

  delay(200);
}

void loop() 
{
  state = digitalRead(PIN_CUT);
  if (state != 1) {
    buf[0] = KEY_LEFT_CTRL;     // Ctrl
    buf[2] = 27;    // Letter X
    // buf[2] = 123;      // Cut key: Less portable
    Serial.write(buf, 8);   // Ssend keypress
    digitalWrite(LED_CUT, HIGH);
    releaseKey();
  } 

  state = digitalRead(PIN_COPY);
  if (state != 1) {
    buf[0] = KEY_LEFT_CTRL;     // Ctrl
    buf[2] = 6;    // Letter C
    // buf[2] = 124;      // Copy key: Less portable
    Serial.write(buf, 8);   // Send keypress
    digitalWrite(LED_COPY, HIGH);
    releaseKey();
  } 

  state = digitalRead(PIN_PASTE);
  if (state != 1) {
    buf[0] = KEY_LEFT_CTRL;     // Ctrl
    buf[2] = 25;    // Letter V
    // buf[2] = 125;      // Paste key: Less portable
    Serial.write(buf, 8);   // Send keypress
       digitalWrite(LED_PASTE, HIGH);
    releaseKey();
  } 
}

void releaseKey() 
{
  buf[0] = 0;
  buf[2] = 0;
  Serial.write(buf, 8); // Release key  
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LED_COPY, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_CUT, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED_PASTE, LOW);
}
```

For refrence this is the article I was using http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/

Comment: How about storing millis() whenever a key is pressed. Lets call it MillisOnLastKeypress. Then you can have an if saying if millis() - 30000 > MillisOnLastKeypress then...   But you should also check for keypresses while your animation is running, so remember to break out of the animation if a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

i recomend you to look for Finite State Machine in Google.

Here is one link to implement it in C++
http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/state-machine-design-in-c/184401236

here is other link to implement it in Arduino
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SMlib

it's exactly what you need to do what you want.

i hope this help you!